# WPF ControlTemplate Expander issue

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

The following code snippetcode has some issue, I don't know where to place it.

```
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ExpandSite" 
                                          Property="Visibility" 
                                          Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` element inside the `<Grid>` instead of directly inside the `<ControlTemplate>`.  Move it down after the line that has `</Grid>` and before the line that has `</ControlTemplate>` so that it is a direct child of the `<ControlTemplate>` element.